# SVN setup... Unable to connect to a repository but can ping host

Tags: svn, networking, tortoisesvn

I have a svn server I'm setting up for a project. I've installed SVN, gotten it up and running with a new SVN user, made user/password combos in the passwrd file and made it available in svnserve.conf. I created a repositories folder in my SVN user folder, and "svnserve -d -r /home/svn/repositories". I make a folder in the repository for my current project...

So I have

```
/home/svn/repositories/my_new_project
```

I run netstat -lntp on my server

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address State  
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3690      0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 
24405/svnserve
...etc...
```

Now, hopping off the server, and hopping on my client machine,  to check the server is up, I

```
ping my_network_server_name_here
```

Pinging my_network_server_name_here [1.2.3.4] with 32 bytes of data:

```
Reply from [1.2.3.4]: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=62
Reply from [1.2.3.4]: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=62
Reply from [1.2.3.4]: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=62
Reply from [1.2.3.4]: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=62
```

And I get a nice ping rate, so I know the server is accessible.
I have tortoiseSVN installed. I right-click on the folder I want to add to the repository, hit import, and send it to

```
svn://my_network_server_name_here:3690/my_new_project
```

The response I get is...

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
svn://my_network_server_name_here/my_new_project
Can't connect to host 'my_network_server_name': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.
```

My question is... where have I screwed up?

Comment: Ping (ICMP-packets) means **nothing** for TCP-connectivity. And this is SU-topic anyway

Comment: I was using ping primarely to check that the server was up and not being firewalled in some major way. Although I don't know a good quick-test for testing TCP-connectivity if you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `svnserve -d -r /home/svn/repositories` URL of repo `svn://my_network_server_name_here:3690/my_new_project` means: you created repository (svnadmin create) in folder `my_new_project`. Is it correct?

Well, `0.0.0.0:3690` means "svnserve listen on all interfaces", but doesn't mean "you can connect to it on all interfaces". Because some tool-in-the-middle can prevent connection to svnserve. You can, using *lightweight commands* in SVN (like `svn ls URL`)

1. Try to connect to repo from host of repo, using hostname `localhost`
2. If OK, connect to repo from host of repo, using FQDN of host
3. IF OK, connect to repo from external host, reducing amount of intermediate hosts on each iteration

Firewall on route expected, which blocks access to not-whilelisted ports

Comment: You're correct that I did the svnadmin create command.

As far as using the `svn ls svn://my_network_server_name_here:3690/my_new_project` goes, gives me the error that it's unable to connect from localhost from the same server (Unable to connect to a repository at URL...) However, doing it from local host gives the additional "svnserve.conf:19 : Option expected." However, I checked the svnserve.conf at line 19, and it's just a commented instruction line.

Comment: Definitely fixed some issues on step 1 & 2, but client still getting same error, and there's nothing between client and host. :/